# calling fgets twice for multiple files

Tags: c, shell, input

I have two files called id.txt and name.txt.

The contents for id and name respectively are:

```
12345
23456
34567
45678
56789
67890

abcde
bcdef
cdefg
defgh
efghi
fghij
```

The problem is that to and store it in a array I have to read the inputs from the command line

Here is my main code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 10

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char id[MAX];
    char name[MAX];

    while(fgets(id, sizeof id, stdin) != NULL)  
    {
        printf("ID: %s\n",id);
    }

    while(fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Name: %s\n",name);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

The last bit is that I have to redirect the input files in the command line.

So my command line argument so far is:

```
 gcc -Wall -ansi -o main main.c     
 ./main < id.txt name.txt
```

The output is:

```
12345

23456

34567

45678

56789

67890
```

From what I understand from fgets() is that when it reaches the end of the file it will return null. So after reading the first file would the first while loop stop and then go to the second while loop.

Comment: where you are using argv in your code ?

Comment: Do I use argv for the file inputs?

Comment: The shell redirected standard input from `id.txt` and passed the string `name.txt` as an argument to your program. You either need to open the file named by `argv[1]`, or you need to rethink what you're doing. It might be neater to pass both file names (as `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`, with `argc == 3`) and open (and close) both files. Note that `fgets()` in the second loop immediately returns EOF because the first loop also detected EOF and you did not clear the 'error' (EOF) condition with `clearerr(stdin)`. However, even if you cleared the error, you'd immediately get another EOF with your code.

Comment: you are just passing files names but not at all using, you need to open the files which you are passing and then read with that file descriptor according to your present code you are trying to read ID and NAME inputs from console.

Comment: Incidentally, the output you show is not the output from the program you show; you've missed the `ID:` tags on each line.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Could you explain the argv

Comment: @Pyrons check my answer and get back to me if any doubt

Comment: Alright I get it now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you are passing file names as command line arguments but not utilizing in source code. please find following code to better understanding.

and run your code as `./main id.txt name.txt`

`argv[1]` and `argv[2]` contains id.txt and name.txt respectively.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 10

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char id[MAX];
    char name[MAX];
    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;
    if(argc==3)
    {
        fp1 = fopen(argv[1],"r");
        fp2 = fopen(argv[2],"r");
        if((fp1==NULL)||(fp2==NULL))
        {
            printf("one of the file is not openend");
        }
        while(fgets(id, sizeof id, fp1) != NULL)  
        {
            printf("ID: %s\n",id);
        }

        while(fgets(name, sizeof name, fp2) != NULL)
        {
            printf("Name: %s\n",name);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please check command line arguments");
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file pointers` to open both the files and then read them. Take names of file at command line and do this -

```
 if(argc!=3){                     //check for incorrect command line arguments
       printf("Not enough arguments");
       return -1;
 }
 FILE *fp1,*fp2; 
 fp1=fopen(argv[1],"r");             //opening file in read mode
 if(fp1==NULL)                       //check return of fopen    
 {
   printf("Cannot open file %s",argv[1]);
 }
 fp2=fopen(argv[2],"r");
 if(fp2==NULL)                       //similarly check for second file
 {
   printf("Cannot open file %s",argv[2]);
 }
```

So statements inside `while loop` should read from the files not from `stdin`. Re-write them-

```
while(fgets(id, sizeof id,fp1)!=NULL){
...
}
while(fgets(id, sizeof id,fp2)!=NULL){
...
}
```

And also rememnber to close files at end -

```
fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best for your purpose is not to use stdin, but read the two filenames from the command line:

The commande line would be this

```
./main id.txt name.txt
```

**Program (no error checking done for sake of simplicity):**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 10
#define MAXLINELENGTH 100

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 3)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "incorrect arguments");
    exit(1);
  }

  FILE *input;  
  char id[MAX];
  char name[MAX];

  input = fopen(argv[1], "r");  // argv[1] points to "id.txt"
  while(fgets(id, sizeof id , input) != NULL)  
  {
      printf("ID: %s\n",id);
  }
  fclose(input);

  input = fopen(argv[2], "r");  // argv[2] points to "name.txt"
  while(fgets(name, sizeof name , input) != NULL)  
  {
      printf("Name: %s\n",name);
  }
  fclose(input);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check code to see how you do it. You need 2 file pointers, to 2 different files. Change argv[1] and argv[2] to specific location if you want to "hardcode" it

```
FILE *fp1;
FILE *fp2;

fp1 = fopen(argv[1],"r");
fp2 = fopen(argv[2],"r");

fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);
```